# Vote showing notification badge in ios for expo notifications

Tags: notifications, expo, badge

I am using expo notification library to generate and manage notifications in my app [expo managed App].
The versions are as follows

- expo SDK Version: 4.22
- expo-notification SDK Version: 3.7
- Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS

I receive notifications properly however in iOS the notification badge is not coming for my app icon.
As per my research, there seems to be 2 ways to show badge:

1. provide ‘badge’ property (badge count) while generating notification in notification payload
2. set badge by using ‘setBadgeCountAsync’ & ‘getBadgeCountAsync’ methods when notification is received.

However I have question regarding both the approaches -
For approach 1,
how to provide correct badge count value while generating notification? Because the service generating notification does not know the current badge count on receiver’s device. Is there a way to get that count to provide it in notification payload?

For approach 2,
Expo provides notification received listeners when app is foregrounded [NotificationReceivedListener] or backgrounded [BackgroundNotificationTask]. However, it does not provide any listener when app is killed. So, is there a way to use ‘setBadgeCountAsync’ & ‘getBadgeCountAsync’ such that it set the proper badge count even if the app is killed?

Or is there any other way to achieve badge display for iOS?

Thanks.